# My 2 computers on same domain with same user id cannot ping each other

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping

I have a Desktop Computer whose name is **CC-PC**. Its operating system is `Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit`. It is a member of domain whose name is **ABC.LOCAL**. So its full computer name is **CC-PC.ABC.LOCAL**. It is connected to internet as wireless through router NETGEAR Nighthawk R7000.

I also have a Laptop Computer whose name is **CC-HP**. Its operating system is `Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit`. It is also a member of same domain whose name is **ABC.LOCAL**. So its full computer name is **CC-HP.ABC.LOCAL**. It is connected to internet as wireless through same router NETGEAR Nighthawk R7000.

Domain **ABC.LOCAL** has a user **chumboChappati**. I use **ABC\chumboChappati** user name to login to both desktop and laptop.

In both desktop and laptop, after I login I use `SonicWALL NetExtender` to connect to a server. I use the same credentials for both desktop and laptop:

- Server: **def.ghi.com**
- Username: **chumboChappati**
- Password: *************
- Domain: **abc.local**

For the desktop computer the `SonicWALL NetExtender` is showing Client IP as **192.168.58.134**.

For the laptop computer the `SonicWALL NetExtender` is showing Client IP as **192.168.58.184**.

---

Now from desktop computer I try to ping laptop computer by typing `ping 192.168.58.184` or `ping CC-HP` in command prompt, but I get error message:

> Request timed out.

Similarly from laptop computer I try to ping desktop computer by typing `ping 192.168.58.134` or `ping CC-PC` in command prompt, but I get error message:

> Request timed out.

What could be the reason? How can I solve this issue?

---

I tried nslookup.

From desktop computer I lookup laptop computer, by typing `nslookup CC-HP` in command prompt, and I get this result:

- Server: **xxyyzz.abc.local**
- Address: **192.168.38.26**
- Name: **CC-HP.ABC.LOCAL**
- Address: **192.168.58.184**

From laptop computer I lookup desktop computer, by typing `nslookup CC-PC` in command prompt, and I get this result:

- Server: **xxyyzz.abc.local**
- Address: **192.168.38.26**
- Name: **CC-PC.ABC.LOCAL**
- Address: **192.168.58.134**

---

Comment: By any means, if the router or the SonicWall utility or anything blocks ICMP the ping will fail.

Comment: Often in SOHO, the local subnet and DNS will be the same such as 192.168.1.1 for the router and DNS/DHCP/etc.  Why is there a 192.168.38.x subnet and a 192.168.58.x subnet?

Answer (score 2):

As both computers are on the same switch (part of your netgear IS a switch), this is not a routing problem.

Both should be able to exchange ICMP messages directly on the local network.

My guess is that the windows firewall of both PC is blocking inbound ICMP messages (or maybe some antivirus or security software you installed). Hence, the ping commands never receive an answer.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's more of a comment.

Comment: How is it not an answer?  The exact question is "What could be the reason?".  Strangelovian clearly stated a reason (albeit a speculative one).

Comment: I have edited the question to include "How can I solve this issue?". jeez I thought it would be implied